Why is there (practically) no 6-byte integer in common usage?
In Postgres, it used to be quite common to use a 4-byte integer auto field for primary keys, until it started becomming somewhat common to run into the 2147483647 limit of 4-byte integers. Now, it's become somewhat common to start with 8-byte integer primary keys, just to be safe, because the small additional cost helps avoid potentially major issues down the road. But, who will ever have a database with 9223372036854775807 (9 billion billion) rows?
This made me wonder why 6-byte integers weren't really a thing. A signed 6 byte integer could hold something like 140 trillion positive values (right?), and would be highly practical for uses like this (database primary keys).
I found this old post, dating back to 2004, asking about 6-byte integers in C. I also found a number of specific technical questions on StackOverflow related to 6-byte integers, but I couldn't find anything well documented or standardized that either A) suggested that 6-byte integers are a common thing, B) should or might become a thing, or C) can't, for some technical reason, become a thing.
Is there any reason why it wouldn't be a good idea, from a performance, practicality, etc. standpoint to have 6-byte integers? Feel free to think about this question in the limited context of C and/or C++, if it helps it avoid being too abstract.
My gut tells me that wide-spread adoption of 6-byte integers would present some kind of big performance boost / RAM savings for a lot of projects, especially in the ML/AI space, as well as some small performance / RAM / space savings in the database world.

Why are you asking about 6 bytes, and not 5? Why not 7?

@Flater why not 41 bits and a qubit?

6 byte integers present a couple of issues related to alignment. A 6 byte integer needs to have an alignment of 2 or less. An alignment of 4 or 8 would result in needing 2 packing bytes in arrays, negating any density advantages over 8 byte math in arrays.
This presents a problem with cache lines. Conventionally the alignment is at least as large as the value, to ensure that the value will not cross a cache line boundary. Crossing a cache line boundary significantly increases both the complexity of the hardware to handle the read (it has to split the read into two transactions, one of 2 and one of 4, each of which could fail), and doubles the latency, as that now needs two cache bus/memory bus transactions rather than one.
That cost likely more than outweighs the 25% improvement in memory density you get from packing in additional values. And in situations where this is worthwhile to reduce main memory bandwidth, the cost of unpacking manually then doing the math in 64bits is unlikely to be a bottleneck.
And for situations where you aren't dealing with arrays, its rare to be dealing with enough copies that 6 vs 8 bytes is significant, and latency from single accesses would likely be dominated by the misalignment costs.

That's of course only because alignments are powers of two. With 6 bit integers that would have to be changed as well. It is not clear to me why powers of two are better.

@freakish  Because addresses are in binary. Which means you can address aligned cache lines by dropping off the bottom n bits of the address bus when doing a memory access. And if cache lines are aligned to a power of 2 boundary, then everything else needs to align that boundary.

I don't see a reason for cache lines or anything else in CPU to use power of two. In fact there were machines that used other sizes, e.g. 24 bit ICL 1900

@freakish Whats important is that the cachelines/words are a power of two of the minimum addressable unit. Most modern machines have bytes as the minimum addressable unit, and so have power of two sized cachelines/words. Mainframes like the ICL 1900 were word addressable, and so they had 1 24 bit addressable unit per word. And 1 is a trivial power of 2. So if you are willing to have your base addressable unit be a multiple of 3 bits, it is doable, but that comes with a whole lot of bigger compromises when it comes to data interchangeability.

Or if want to be really into the weeds, its that words and cache lines should be a power of the symbol count times base addressable unit. If you had a ternary computer, then powers of 3 would be relevant.

@freakish, The word size of a 60-year-old computer is irrelevant here. Address arithmetic (and the fact of it being done in binary) matters in modern computers because modern computers can do something that the ICL 1900 could not do. Most modern computers can address and operate on units of memory (bytes) that are smaller than the size of a memory word.  There needs to be a way to map byte addresses to word addresses, and if address arithmetic is done in binary, then the simplest way is to have a power-of-two bytes per word, and convert by simply dropping the lowest order address bits.

@SolomonSlow sorry, but literally nothing in your comment indicates that powers of two are superior. We don't aim at simplicity, we aim at better, faster, etc. Simplicity is not a goal, in fact the last thing I would say about modern CPUs/architectures is that they are simple.

@user1937198 honestly I don't see why we need powers to address cachelines. Regardless, I was more interested in base 2, rather than being a power. I wonder whether different bases can be better...

Its the bus geometry. For an m bit address you need m lines. For an m bit address aligned to the nth power of the base, you just take the top m-n lines, and that's the bus address. Any other scheme for calculating bus addresses is more complex and requires more lines.

@freakish Simplicitly is absolutely a goal of modern architectures. They are designed to be the simplest possible design that meets all the performance and compatibility requirements. Because complexity makes performance harder and reduces yields. If there is a solution that is simple, zero power, and zero latency? You better have a good reason for doing something else.

@user1937198 yes, power, latency and performance is absolutely a reason to don't care about simplicity. We keep inventing new and more complex and sophisticated stuff, because those old and simple are simply worse. So there has to be some other reason. Of course it may as well be a snowball effect. So many things now depend on it, that it is practically impossible to change.

@CriticizingIsraelnotallowed which doesn't address what I've been taking about at all. I'm asking why base 2 is supposedly better than other bases for entire architecture, for entire system. Because that's the only way to explain why we don't see 6-byte integers. It is rather obvious that 6-byte integers will be slow on 2^n byte machine. But that is not what I call an explanation, it's rather shallow.

@freakish base 3 is annoyingly difficult to design for, because it just doesn't match how transistors work. You only get 2 saturation regions. Base 4 gets some interest, because you can work with a pair of transistors, but tends to only be seen in places where the density of signals massively outweighs the cost of processing hardware (storage, external highbandwidth interfaces etc).

A transistor can be modeled as something of an S-shaped curve of  input to output. At each end of the curve, output is very close to equal to one of the input signals. This leads to the nice property where any loss/noise on a signal is attenuated, rather than amplified resulting in reliable transmission. In the middle its an analogue mix of the two inputs, such that a small change in one input results in a larger change in the output, amplifying any noise/loss, resulting in a loss of the signal after going through too many gates, if you don't add conditioning.

@user1937198 I've done some research and I found an interesting paper: "Design implementations of ternary logic systems: A critical review" where they claim that ternary systems require -37% less operations and store more information than binary. It may be annoying but it seems there is potential in it. They also mention several difficulties, one of them actually being "incompatibilities with technological advancements". What I've suspected earlier.

So they are talking about material engineering at the level of what is arguably a novel 3 terminal semiconductor, not transistors. Which is a massive change at a very fundamental level which needs a bunch of changes up the stack. And then also opens the question: Why not quaternary? If you can make the appropriate band gaps reliably, then that might result in bigger savings, and is easier to interface with the rest of the technical world that is built on the simpler binary model.

@user1937198 there are certain advantages of ternary model. Emulating it with binary or quaternary is likely to be inefficient. I'm not saying quaternary is worse though. I'm not an expert in the field, I'm just saying that it is not obvious at all that binary is superior to other designs. And saying "because it is simple" honestly sounds like an excuse rather than deep understanding.

@freakish You are welcome to actually design toy versions of all these architectures and see how your designs differ.

There are two separate issues here:

Memory usage
Processor support for 6 byte integer math.

These issues are somewhat independent, in that a lot of the time numbers are just shuffled around between variables and data structure (no arithmetic operations are performed on them) so even without processor support a language could be designed to only store integers in 6 bytes (inside structures), for one off variables you could still use 8 bytes and use 8 byte arithmetic functions (although you might need extra code for overflow conditions).
If you add 6 byte math support to the processor it would likely have a significant impact on the design of the processor as there would need to be additional instructions added to the processor and this may have downstream effects on other parts of the processor (for example cache lines). I doubt there is a significant enough ROI (extra cost of both design and manufacturing) to justify the extra complexity, given the potential for slightly fast execution of code, even assuming a perfect implementation you are only going to gain a 33% improvement (6 vs 8 bytes moved) in performance for the cases that can benefit from it.
I would also question how much we as programmers want to think about different sizes of integers (premature optimization argument), in that I usually just use Int (32 bit) ** even if byte or short might work, I typically only switch to long for really big numbers or byte if I am processing binary data.
** - I would consider short or byte, if I am storing a lot of them (i.e. allocate a large array of short).

Thanks for all the info - I ultimately picked the other answer, because it gave a more concrete set of reasons for the lack of standard support, but this is also a terrific answer. I wish I could choose both.

The other answers about the convenience of power-of-two sizes being simpler for addressing are undoubtedly correct, but it's perhaps worth pointing out that there are 6-byte integers in common use, for some value of "common".
Specifically, IEEE 802 MAC address are 6 bytes, which means 6-byte values are used on every Ethernet and Wi-fi packet in the world.
Non-standard (ie, non power-of-two) sizes are always possible. It's just that they're preferred in situations where space is more important than simplicity. It's also relevant that although these really are integer values, they are mostly not used for integer arithmetic.

There also not unusual to see in DSP architectures, where processing 32 bit samples, without loss of precision in intermediary operations is needed, but large memory spaces and the ability to program in higher level languages are not considered important.

It’s historical. When hardware manufacturers could improve on 32 bit numbers, they checked that 64 bit was more of a long term solution and easier to implement. For example array indexing can be done by shifting the
Index by three bit positions instead of using a multiplication by 6. 8 bytes can be simulated by using 2x4 bytes.
There’s not much difference but some, and you don’t want both 48 and 64 it hardware. Which means 48 bits makes you fall behind the competition.

From a hardware point of view, shift by 3 is a lot cheaper than multiplication by 6. Shift by 3 can be done trivially by arranging the address line interconnects if you know its a fixed shift. Multiply by 6 however requires a bunch of logic to calculate ((x << 1) + x) And division by 6 requires a divider.
